# cherrypy 404 not found

Tags: php, python, cherrypy

I would like to access 2 php files from my cherrypy app. 
I can get to dbmgmt.php from the cherrypy app using jQuery.

```
$('#dbmgmt').click(function(){
    window.location.href='static/dbmgmt.php';
});
```

This is in `dbmgmt.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="addEntry.php">
        <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
            <legend>New Entry</legend>
            <label for="patientID">Patient ID:</label>
            <input name="patientID" id="patientID" placeholder="2 characters follow by 3 digits" value="" type="text" required>
            <label for="firstname">Patient Name:</label>
            <input name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="" type="text" required>
            <input name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="" type="text">
            <label for="patientIC">Patient IC:</label>
            <input name="patientIC" id="patientIC" placeholder="Patient IC" value="" type="text" required>
            <label for="address">Address:</label>
            <input name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" value="" type="text">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
            <input name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" value="" type="text">

            <input value="Submit" type="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

This is in `addEntry.php`:

```
<?php
echo "test";
$patientID = $_POST['patientID'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$patientIC = $_POST['patientIC'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'yusiang', 'lalalulu', 'hospital');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
     exit;
}
mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO PATIENT (patient_ID, first_name, last_name, patient_IC, address, phone)
VALUES ('$patientID', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$patientIC', '$address', '$phone')");

echo "Thank you!";
//header ('Location: dbmgmt.php');
     ?>
```

However I get the following error:

```
    404 Not Found

The path '/static/addEntry.php' was not found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 386, in __call__
    raise self
NotFound: (404, "The path '/static/addEntry.php' was not found.")
```

I read on some questions regarding 404 but i couldn't find a concrete solution to my question. 
Note: both dbmgmt.php and addEntry.php are in `static` folder together with other css or js files.

Comment: If the page is stored on a webserver, you will never fetch the PHP, only the result of PHP code execution...

Comment: @CommuSoft in order to test whether the PHP code has been executed or not, i tried to use `echo`. unfortunately, the data was not entered into the database as well.

Comment: As I already stated, when you fetched the page, you didn't send any `$_POST` data with the query. So it's more than logical, the PHP code will crash on the first line.

Comment: hmm? I don't get you.I did send the data from dbmgmt.php using $_POST right? sorry i'm not familiar with php :(

Comment: No, you only send data when you *submit* the form, what you do here is you redirect to a new page losing all data entered.

Comment: hmm, that's confusing. I redirect to this page when i click the `submit` button, no? without the `echo`, it will only shows `error loading page`temporary and not even showing the errors.

Comment: When you submit a form, two things happen: the browser assembles all entered information of the form into a HTTP header (the PHP server will receive this and turn it into `$_POST`) and a redirects to the `action` page, when you simply redirect, the first step is never exectuted.